# Do I use an apostrophe if I'm referring to several medical IVs?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, apostrophe, acronyms, medical

First sentence (with apostrophe):

> The IV's continued to drip as she thrashed on the bed.

OR

Second sentence (no apostrophe):

> The IVs continued to drip as she thrashed on the bed.

Which one of these sentences is correct? Why would you or why wouldn't you use an apostrophe in this case?

Comment: Margaret, in my edit I've changed *trashed* to *thrashed*, as I suspect that is the more likely intention in this sentence. I suppose a patient could *trash* on a bed, but it's a non-standard expression, and in my mind suggests a bodily function we would use a different verb for. ;-)

Comment: @Chappo Yes, thank you for editing my hurried question xD